# Workmanager plugin to run camera in background

Tags: background, camera

I want to run camera in background of android app. Currently the camera gets stuck after 1 minute of working in background. That could be probably due to background limits provided by android.

Can workmanager resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The issue has been partially resolved by the use of foreground service to run camera in background.